# Has gold tag badge question closing been removed?

Tags: discussion, support

I can no longer close questions with simply my vote.

Previously I could close photoshop and Illustrator tagged questions with one vote because I have the gold badge for the [adobe-photosop](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe-photosop) and [adobe-illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe-illustrator) tags.

Has this ability been removed?

Fine either way.. just noticed the change in behavior today.

Comment: Was it a duplicate that you tried to close? I think the power only works for duplicates, right?

Comment: Okay.. so thanks for pointing out how clueless I am at times John :)

Comment: Don;t you just LOVE posting something to show off your ignorance??? :)

Comment: Tempting to tag this as [meta-tag:featured] to further rub it in...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [dupehammer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/244929), not a generic closehammer. Gold badgers have extra weight when voting on dupes only.

Comment: Yup.. John just pointed that out as well.  thanks. I'd have deleted this question... but... not with an answer :)

Comment: "dupehammer" and "closehammer." I love tools with such deliciously descriptive names. :)